# How to correctly identify shapes on noisy images?

Tags: python, opencv

I am experiencing problem with choosing proper shape detection algorithm. My task is to identify shapes on playing cards of "Geometric game". Example image:

[image: Input 1]

By identifying I mean that my algorithm should understand the number of vertices of each shape. If it is a circle, it should also understand that.
For solving my problem, I tried to apply some kind of filtering (Kirsch filter) and openCV `findCountours` procedure. But there is a problem - sometimes shapes are not continious because of presence of background. Can you recommend what algorithms or group of algorithms I need to try to deal with background and also properly identify shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We as human know the cards are on the carpet because we have a 3D model in our mind, and we have an expectation on what is covered under the cards based on our experience.

You will need to provide both knowledge above to machine as well. One way to do this is background subtraction.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html

This is to tell the machine that the target objects are on top of a meaningless background, and what the expected background looks like. You can also try the image segmentation algorithms from opencv.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html

I don't think it will work that well on the kind of background you have. But it's easy enough to try it out.

Based on the expectation of blue color cards, you can also try mean shift filtering for blue color. Try it to see if it works.

http://www.chioka.in/meanshift-algorithm-for-the-rest-of-us-python/

The keywords you are looking for are image segmentation, object detection, background filtering. Once you have the target objects masked out, you can perform usual edge/line detection and corner detection for shape classification. <--- a lot of work

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'll maybe try to add 'histograms of gradient directions' or [HOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) in the picture as well, then you could try to compare their similarity to some "truth" using whatever loss function that works best.